# How to add a shaded rectangle to the part of a plot meeting a certain condition?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset for body temprature of a subject at different time points since a bacteria challenge.

```
Temprature  time since challenge(in hours)
36                  9
36.5                12
37                  24
38                  36
38.4                49
37                  60
38.3                72
```

If the body temprature is more than 38 for at least 12 hours, it means the person has got ill, so I would like to add a shaded rectangle and a segment to the part of the plot which has this condition.

I am using ggplot to plot the data,

```
p<-ggplot(data, aes(factor(x=time,levels=time), y=temprature, group=1)) +geom_line()+ geom_point()+
  geom_hline(yintercept=38,color = "blue")

p+annotate("rect", xmin="132:35", xmax="180:35", ymin=38, ymax=38.5, alpha=.1, fill="blue")

s<-q+annotate("segment", x="132:35", xend="180:35", y=38.35, yend=38.35, arrow=arrow(ends="both",angle=90, length=unit(.2,"cm")))


p1<-s+annotate("text",x="157:35", y=38.5, label=">12 h")+xlab("Time since challenge") + ylab("Temprature")

p1
```

This code adds the rectangle to the plot manually, but I would like to write a code which adds the shaded rectangle and the segment automatically to the plot, using the condition of having temprature of >38 for more than 12 h. Because this code will be replicated for all the subjects.

DO you know how one can do that?

Answer (score 0):

I took the liberty of adding a likely more complicated case, when there are more measurements that sum up to intervals of 12h with temperature >=38 degrees.
There might be more elegant solutions, but this one works.

```
df=data.frame(Temperature=c(36,36.5,37,38,38.4,37,38.3,39,38.3,35,36),
              time_since_challenge=c(9,12,24,36,49,60,72,78,84,90,96))

#define variables
df$interval_start=NA
df$interval_end=NA
df$Temp_interval_start=NA
df$Temp_interval_end=NA

for(i in 1:(nrow(df)-1)){ #-1 so it doesn't run again in the last df-line
  k=0
  if(df$Temperature[i]>=38& df$Temperature[i+1]>=38){

    while(df$Temperature[i+k]>=38){ #needed to address the case of multiple measurements above 12 degrees
      interval_end=i+k
      k=k+1
    }
    df$interval_start[i]=df$time_since_challenge[i]
    df$interval_end[i]=df$time_since_challenge[i+k-1]
    df$Temp_interval_start[i]=df$Temperature[i]
    df$Temp_interval_end[i]=df$Temperature[i+k-1]
  }
}

df_intervals=df[(!is.na(df$interval_end)),] #take only cases that should get the rectangle
df_intervals=df_intervals[!(duplicated(df_intervals$interval_end)),] #remove overlapping intervals

#added time above 38 degrees
df_intervals$Time_above_38degrees=df_intervals$interval_end-df_intervals$interval_start


ggplot(df, aes(x=time_since_challenge, y=Temperature)) +
  geom_rect(data=df_intervals,
            aes(xmin=interval_start,
                xmax=interval_end,
                ymin=Temp_interval_start, #could be hardcoded to 38
                ymax=Temp_interval_end), #could be hardcoded to Inf ,then it would always go up to the yaxis end
            fill="blue",alpha=0.5)+ #added alpha for shading
  geom_line(aes(group=1))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_hline(yintercept=38,color = "blue")+
  geom_segment(data=df_intervals,aes(x=interval_start,xend=interval_end,y=38,yend=38),
               color="red",arrow=arrow(ends="both",angle=90, length=unit(.2,"cm")))
```

Comment: Thanks alot @TobiO, it works well, where can I determine the number of hours above 38, I need to add a text containing the number of hours having temprature above 38, and if it is >12 the person is ill. I am adding it manually: ``p4+
  annotate("text",x=140*60, y=38.3, label="11 h")+annotate("text",x=168*60, y=38.3, label="10 h")`` Is your if loop calculating the number of hours above 38?

Comment: I updated my answer accordingly. It's just a simple subtraction ;-) Have a look at `paste` and just add a `geom_text` to the plot